# when in text/edit and wanting to print document, how do I reduce the font size. I have a MacBook

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I have a document located in text/edit and I would like to reduce the print size before printing on printer.  How do I do this.  I have a MacBook

Answer (score 0):

by 'text/edit' I'm assuming you mean TextEdit

First, if it's not already set to page layout 'Wrap to Page', then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  to activate that, then you can see how it will flow to a printed page.

Select all text with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  then
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>  to reduce overall font size or
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>  to increase.

This will only affect text, not any embedded pictures. They would need to be edited separately in an external photo editor.